# Get error trying to build for WebGL on Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, .net-standard

Get error with UnityLinker.exe trying to build project for WebGL.

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJZ6W.png)

I think this is the most important part:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver..ctor(String[] args)
   at Unity.Linker.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

What can I do? I searched but can't find a solution

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have installed wrong version of WebGL module. Try to reinstall it by Unity Downloader.